# Running python scripts when logged out (selenium)

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, automation, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script that checks for a trigger and after it sees this trigger is run a selenium def. I have to run this while logged out for security reasons and the app needs access to outlook.exe as i use win32com to check the trigger. So my question is this at all possible? right now i cant even run a python script when logged out NOTE it works when started as only when user is logged in. Any help would be appreciated

I have looked for days and cant find an answer to this. I know the script works when logged in

Comment: everything is possible. You provided no info. No code. No error. what do you expect?